# The external style sheet is not working on my site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So i have like triple checked the code cant see the error. I even tried inspecting the page and it doesn't find the files. If you visit zoeaa.com you will see just html no styling. What am I doing wrong?

```
<head>

<meta name="descri
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/web/assets/mobirise- 
icons/mobirise-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/tether/tether.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap- 
grid.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap- 
reboot.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/dropdown/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/theme/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/application/widgets/homepagesystem/assets/mobirise/css/mbr- 
additional.css" type="text/css">  
</head>
```

Comment: Your paths are wrong. Load your site and open the developer console

Comment: To my knowledge my paths are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path has to start from where this html page is, so for instance if this let's call it index.html is inside let's say "mainFolder", in order to work the "application" folder also has to be inside "mainFolder".

If it's not check via ftp the whole path from the css file to where the "index.html" is and that is the correct path (no need of the full url with the domain as mentioned above, that's not the issue).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use absolute paths when referencing files.

Include the site name e.g. `https://www.example.org/app/css/styles.css`.

This is because if you go to a sub directory and you have your src setup like `/app/css/styles.css` the server will try to find your file on `https://www.example.org/my-sub-dir/app/css/styles.css`

Also a side note. bring all your files in together as your just causing more requests. HTTP works faster with larger files and less files to download.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your meta name might not be getting closed (missing the ">). That could definitely be interfering with things working properly. If you're sure the paths are correct that's the only thing I could see that might be an issue.

Hope that does it!

Answer (score 0):

Is it typo mistake or something? But I cant see closing tag `>` in `meta`. + When I opend the site you provided and checked the developer consoler , I found error.